# SQL Server : which role grants permission to execute all stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, security

Which database role membership grants permission to execute all existing stored procedures in SQL Server 2012?

I tried adding a user to each of them and am still unable to execute a stored procedure. I don't want to grant `EXECUTE` for each stored procedure separately, I want to add the user to a role and he be able to execute any of them.

Comment: if all your stored procs are in the same schema you could grant execute on the schema. GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [login]. Other than that I believe db_owner but this would give all sorts of access

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you are using schemas other than the default `dbo` schema, create a database role per schema and grant `EXECUTE` on the schema to the role.

e.g.
For the default `dbo` schema:

```
CREATE ROLE role_exec_dbo
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::dbo to role_exec_dbo
GO
```

For a new schema:

```
CREATE SCHEMA mySchema
GO
CREATE ROLE role_exec_mySchema
GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::mySchema to role_exec_mySchema
GO
```

Comment: Then `exec sp_addrolemember N'role_exec_mySchema', N'{theDBUserName}'`. :-)

Comment: The preferred way of adding users/members to a role is through the `ALTER ROLE Foo ADD MEMBER Bar` statements. `sp_addrolemember` is flagged as maintance and may be removed in the future. As per microsofts documentation.

Answer (score 6):

None by default.

Create a new role and grant execute to it.  This should cover stored procs created in the future as well.

Comment: what about sysadmin?

Comment: ... and db_owner?